# Java Records vs Kotlin Data Classes

Tags: java, kotlin, data-class, java-record

Java 14 offers a new feature called [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359), helping to create JavaBeans. What is the difference between Kotlin's data classes and Java records?

Comment: Indeed, they are fundamentally similar., mostly. [This article](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/amber/datum.html) provides a hint. But the question seems too broad to fit in here in my opinion.

Comment: @Naman, Brian Goetz reminds me that data classes are a _far_ more complex subject than I ever would have imagined.

Comment: @Naman Can we use Java records in Kotlin code (if I run my application on JDK 15)?

Comment: @Sergey not that I know of, not very hands-on with Kotlin :|

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[This is a great article about all those differences.](https://medium.com/javarevisited/javas-records-vs-kotlin-s-data-classes-b3fef851155a)

In summary:

### Similarities

- generated methods: `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`
- generated constructor
- generated getters (but Kotlin getter is called `o.name`, while Java uses  `o.name()`)
- can modify the canonical constructor
- can add additional methods

### Differences

Kotlin's data classes support many other little things:

| [data class (Kotlin)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) | [record (Java)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) |
| --- | --- |
| `copy` method for easier object creation | no `copy` method |
| variables can be `var` or `val` | variables can only be `final` |
| can inherit from other non-data classes | no inheritance |
| can define non-constructor mutable variables | can define only static variables |

Both are great for reducing the code bloat.